# Why object provides __reduce__ by default?

Tags: python, class, object

```
>>> class C(object):
...  pass
...
>>> c=C()
>>> c.__reduce__
<built-in method __reduce__ of C object at 0x1ae734>
```

Does this `__reduce__` do anything if I don't implement it?

Normally we add methods only when necessary, e.g. add `__getitem__` to implement `self[key]`, add `__sub__` to implement `x-y`... So I guess it must do something by default? Otherwise it should be omitted..

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__

Comment: I understand `__reduce__` is for pickle, but why it is a must for object? For example `__getstate__` can influence pickle too, but it is not provided in object.